# PHP MySQL date format search

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to create a query that takes the users input from a text field called $incorporation_date.

Query Idea

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE incorporation_date LIKE '%%%%/%%/%%" . $incorporation_date . "%%%%/%%/%%'";
```

How would I make it so that you could use SQL to bring up the values of the submitted format you enter.

Example search 2015-06-15

Comment: What datatype is your `incorporation_date` column? Please don't say it's a varchar!

Comment: Use equal sign. YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: the datatype is a date.

Comment: Where theDate='2014-04-07'. Beware of sql injection

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Date` or `Datetime` and spare yourself of the grief that would otherwise follow were it not

```
drop table theGuy;

create table theGuy
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    fullName varchar(60) not null,
    birthDate date not null
);

insert theGuy (fullName,birthDate) values ('Kim Smithers','2002-3-1'),('John Doe','2014-4-5');

select * from theGuy where birthDate>='2000-1-1' and birthDate<='2007-12-31';

select * from theGuy where birthDate between '2000-1-1' and '2007-12-31';


select *,birthDate+interval 45 DAY as BirthCertAvail from theGuy;

select *,datediff(curdate(),birthDate) as DaysAlive from theGuy;
```

You might find the built-in routines adequate, such as intervals, without having to rewrite them. ;)

Comment: Cool you are using datetime. Some wacky homegrown schemas and bizarreness from some peeps

Comment: To get datepart of `datetime` that may contain not stroke of midnight time in it use function date()

Comment: can you not have it to search a custom date range? from user input

Comment: You can but you need to cleanse it especially when using mysql_* deprecated technology. Search on sql injection ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php